# Sending mails in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've a form that outputs URL string like:

```
address=someaddress&title=Title&name=Author&mail=authorsmail&message=Somemessage
```

(I'm doing it using jQuery AJAX function)

```
  $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "send.php",  
        data: myString,
(...)
```

Anyways, there is something wrong with my send.php file, because I'm trying and trying and I'm unable to get any mails.

```
$mailTo = Trim(stripslashes($_GET['address']));
$subject = Trim(stripslashes($_GET['title']));
$name = Trim(stripslashes($_GET['name'])); 
$emailFrom = Trim(stripslashes($_GET['mail'])); 
$message = Trim(stripslashes($_GET['message'])); 

$Body = $message;

$success = mail($mailTo, $subject, $Body, "From: <$emailFrom>");
```

It doesn't work when i change all $_POST to $_GET.

What's wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: have you set myString in the data parameter to your query string that was in your URL? can you try setting it as a javascript object instead of a query string like that?

Comment: data is set in jQuery, it shows everything fine when I display it via alert.

Comment: Is mail() works with hardcoded values? Your code seems to be OK, just with `$_POST` values.

Comment: Is `SMTP` configured in `php.ini`?

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use $_REQUEST, which works with either POST or GET.

Answer (score 0):

if you change post to get you must change the php variable `$_POST` to `$_GET`
for example

```
Trim(stripslashes($_POST['address']));
```

to

```
Trim(stripslashes($_GET['address']));
```

Comment: Nothing as I said before, I've just edited the first post so next users will focus on other things (I believe there's one small mistake in the code somewhrere, but can't figure out where ;s)

Answer (score 0):

I think something is wrong with your question.

You say your AJAX script results in a URL string such as `address=someaddress&title=Title&name=Author&mail=authorsmail&message=Somemessage`, yet your AJAX type is set to POST, which would not result in that URL.  Are you sure your JavaScript is working properly?  Are you sure your JavaScript is stopping the actual form submission?

Comment: They do the same there and it works: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/comment-page-1/#comments